# How to Collapsable Dropdown List React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having trouble creating a collapsable dropdown list. I have a feeling it's due to the data format I'm mapping through or if it's because I'm nesting a map within a map. Or because I should be doing it outside of the render. I'm not sure, I'm feeling burnt out on it and just need an extra pair of eyes.

```
export default class GardenList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      visibleItems: null,
      isChecked: null
    }

  }

  toggleMenu(i){
    var newI = i;
    this.state.visibleItems === i ? (newI = null) : null;
    this.setState({
      visibleItems: newI
    })
  }

  toggleCheck(i){
    this.setState({
      isChecked: i
    })
  }

    render(){

      const methods = [
        'Permaculture',
        'Home Compost',
        'Companion Planting',
        'Intensive Gardening',
        'Spin Farming',
        'Intregrated Pest Management'];

      const soil = ['Gypsum', 'BioChar'];

      const space = ['Unframed Beds', 'Straw Bale Beds', 'Vertical Gardening'];

      const listAndType = [
        {name: 'Growing methods', type: methods },
        {name: 'Soil ammendments', type: soil},
        {name: 'Plant space', type: space}
      ];



      return(
        <View style={ baseStyles.profileContainer }>
          <View style={baseStyles.listContainer1}>
            {
              listAndType.map((item, i) => (
                <View key={i}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.toggleMenu(i)}>
                    <View style={ baseStyles.touchableList }>
                      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                      {this.state.visibleItems === i ? icon1 : icon2}
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>

                  {/*This is where I'm trying to have a list of types show up*/}

                </View>
              ))
            }


          </View>

        </View>
      )
  }

}
```

So where my comment is, I was thinking about mapping through the array that belonged to that object. So if I toggledMenu on the first `TouchableOpacity`, a list of `types` will drop down. I'm having trouble accessing those `types` though.

I was thinking within the initial map I would map through the first type list using the key index. Something like `item[i].map((type, index) => etc` but getting an undefined error. I tried various things but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While this may not answer your question directly, I have a suggestion.

Mobile UIs aren't great with things like drop down lists, you have all sorts of issues with positioning, small screens and fat fingers. I know sometimes its what a client insists on, but what I have found this workflow is better:

1. Have the user click on a control
2. Push a new screen on to the navigation stack which the user can select something from, or display a modal.
3. Return user to original control with the item selected.

The benefit of this UI is you can include a search function at the top of the list or add some other logic to make the user's life easier.

An alternative if you don't have many items to select from is using a radio button style control, but this should be very limited to small items.

If you want to see these two workflows in action, I have a form builder app that utilised both as described - https://www.efrs.io. Add a "QuickPick" control and you can toggle between both types.

Comment: I really like your suggestion!! Esp since they want extra features on this page. I'll suggest this tomorrow and see what my people may say. thx!